# Ubuntu 18.10 freezes within 10 seconds after log in

Tags: asus, freeze

I have installed ubuntu 18.10 on my asus rog gl-553vd. But after logging in the display is freezing after 10 seconds.

Can you guys please help me  out?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the nVidia graphics card. You can fix it adding the grub config parameter `nouveau.modeset=0`. You can see how to do this in this video: https://youtu.be/NOg5ILhTYNY

Comment: Why the downvote? Did someone try the proposed solution?

Comment: @dmdip I solved that problem by installing nvidia graphics driver and now I am facing another problem..fans are spinning constantly though cpu usage is under 20% and only using google chrome with 2 tabs..